# localhost loads only in Chrome, no other browsers

Tags: debugging, localhost, iis-express

After a recent windows update, I am unable to load localhost in any browser except chrome. Chrome works perfectly fine, but all other sites will not load. This happens in the default website http://localhost/ as well as when debugging in Visual studio.

I've researched many issues regarding this, but most refer to it not working in one browser, rather than multiple. I've checked my host file, which is empty, as is my co-workers. I've tried debugging from Visual Studio, as well as just launching the default website directly from IIS.

I have tried enabling script debugging in visual studio, but I don't believe this has anything to do with visual studio, since the default website http://localhost/ won't load either.

There isn't any code that I think is causing this issue, since the basic localhost page won't load, nor will a default startup project.

In firefox, i do not receive any errors in the console, but in Edge I receive this, which has nothing to do with the website I am trying to launch.

SEC7120: [CORS] The origin 'ms-appx-web://microsoft.microsoftedge' failed to allow a cross-origin font resource at 'ms-appx-web:///assets/Fonts/BrowserMDL.ttf#Browser MDL2 Assets'.

CSS3119: No fonts available for @font-face rule
ErrorPageStyles.css (11,7)

It does seem to hit my web project's startup.cs file, but doesn't go anywhere after that.